# c# bind 2 lists to repeater

Tags: c#, linq, list, repeater, bind

[c# linq]

i have 2 datasources, 1 coming from an xml document and 1 coming from an sql server database, both return an `IEnumerable<EventsDetails>` is it possible to bind both of these lists to a single repeater?

Comment: Are you talking about nesting these (as in the two datasources have a parent/child relationship), or just having one repeater bound to two items at the same time?  (or perhaps at some times it's bound to the xml doc and others, it's bound to the sql server DB but bot hhave similar field names)

Comment: Hi David
it is one repeater bound to two items at the same time
thanks
kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this, if you want to use LINQ:

```
var both= list1.Union(list2);
```

Then `both` is your data source.

Comment: How can I ensure if there is two separate labels that each label gets each list? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255119/how-to-populate-two-separate-repeaters-with-distinct-column-name-and-the-value-c

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list containing both. Or an object implementing IEnumetator which first returns elements from the first, then from the second list.